# Logstash Remove '/' at the end of string if exists

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to remove '/' if exists from the end of a string, in Logstash using ruby for example:
'example/' -> 'example'
'other_example' -> 'other_example'

I tried:

```
url = evnet.get("[url]")
if url[-1] == '/'
   url.slice!(-1)
end
```

But it didn't work, I believe I should write the "/" in a different way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using event.get creates a local variable in the ruby filter, which your .slice then modifies. If you want to save that back to the event then you need to call `event.set("[url]", url)`. That said, it might be easier to just

```
mutate { gsub => [ "url", "/$", "" ] }
```